# Using CREATE TYPE to create a new type that is a `time` and a `datetime`

Tags: sql-server, date-formatting

I'd like to create a SQL Server data type using `CREATE TYPE` that combines `time` and `datetime`.

An example string is: `Nov 23, 2009 12:00:00 EST`

It would look something like `FORMAT(@field,'MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss')`.

Is it possible to do this with `CREATE TYPE` or is some other function needed?

Comment: `datetime` already includes time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CREATE TYPE to create a datatype that represents a varchar with a CHECK constraint that only accepts values in the specified format.   If that's what you're asking.